# Expected status code 200 but received 302. Failed asserting that false is true. using phpunit test in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, phpunit

Hi i have this page which is /dno-personal/cebu-properties. I tried to run in using PHPUNIT test in my laravel. Now i created this test file below

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;


class DnoPersonalTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @test
     */
    public function add_cebu_properties_page()
    {


        $response = $this->get('/dno-personal/cebu-properties');
        $response->assertStatus(200);

    }
}
```

Now in my route file i i did not create a route for dno-personal/cebu-properties yet which i run test into my phpunit it throws an error of

```
Expected status code 200 but received 404.
Failed asserting that false is true.

C:\xampp\htdocs\dnogroup\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse.php:79
C:\xampp\htdocs\dnogroup\tests\Feature\DnoPersonalTest.php:24

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

which i think is okay cause i have no route yet which throws an error of 404. 
Now when i add into the route

```
Route::get('/dno-personal/cebu-properties',
        'DnoPersonalController@cebuProperties')
        ->name('dno-personal.cebuProperties');
```

without a method into my controller cebuProperties when i run test PHPUNIT it throws

```
Expected status code 200 but received 302.
Failed asserting that false is true.

C:\xampp\htdocs\dnogroup\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse.php:79
C:\xampp\htdocs\dnogroup\tests\Feature\DnoPersonalTest.php:24

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

it throws an error of 302. Now i want that it throws the method is not yet created instead of 302. 
now when i add `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();` this throws me an error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Tests\Feature\DnoPersonalTest::withoutExceptionHandling() in C:\xampp\htdocs\dnogroup\tests\Feature\DnoPersonalTest.php on line 22

In DnoPersonalTest.php line 22:

  Call to undefined method Tests\Feature\DnoPersonalTest::withoutExceptionHandling()



Fatal error: Call to undefined method Tests\Feature\DnoPersonalTest::withoutExceptionHandling() in C:\xampp\htdocs\dnogroup\tests\Feature\DnoPersonalTest.php on line 22
```

it cannot see the `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();` can someone help me figured this out? Any help is muchly appreciated. TIA

Comment: `withoutExceptionHandling` is not available in Laravel 5.4, it was added in Laravel 5.5. You can find the commit [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/a171f44594c248afe066fee74fad640765b12da0#diff-4e4a438cd863ed9b82a23738402dae21)

Comment: okay thanks but why is that it returns 302 when i already have created a route on that page

Comment: I can't tell you from the code you provided, maybe it gets redirected because of a middleware? Is the route definition inside a route group?

Comment: i want to test $response->assertStatus(200); would pass cause i already created a route why it throws a 302

Comment: yes its inside the route group 
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function(){
    Route::get('/dno-personal/cebu-properties',
  'DnoPersonalController@cebuProperties')
  ->name('dno-personal.cebuProperties');
});

Here

Comment: The `auth` middleware is the problem, this route is only accessible for authenticated users, thats why you are getting a 302, the test is being redirected to the login page.

Comment: yes my middleware is authenticated. so how do i achieved this one?

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that your route applies the `auth` middleware, which means that the request is redirect to the login page before even reaching your route.

You will have to create and authenticate a user to test this route properly, Laravel has the `actingAs` helper for this.

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/http-tests#session-and-authentication):

> Of course, one common use of the session is for maintaining state for
>   the authenticated user. The actingAs helper method provides a simple
>   way to authenticate a given user as the current user. For example, we
>   may use a model factory to generate and authenticate a user:

```
<?php

use App\User;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testApplication()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();

        $response = $this->actingAs($user)
                         ->withSession(['foo' => 'bar'])
                         ->get('/');
    }
}
```

Comment: okay thanks for this so everytime i create a phpunit test i will have to use the authentication  correct?

Comment: Only if you want to test something that requires authentication.

Comment: okay i see that using withSession to authenticate is that correct?

Comment: `withSession` just puts something in the session, in order to authenticate the user for the request you use the `actingAs`  method.

Answer (score 5):

This happens when I test a case that should return 422 status, which is a validation case. I solved it by defining the headers in the test. So make sure to use `Accept: application/json` like this:

```php
        $this
            ->withHeaders(['Accept' => 'application/json'])
            ->post("api/{$this->apiVersion}/auth/register", $requestBody)
            ->assertStatus(422);
```

ref: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#spa-authentication

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using a personalized request that redirects, because the validate fails. I set the default request and works fine, before I review the data and my personalized request works fine too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).